# Scala Transform DF into RDD - error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "age"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing baby steps in scala and spark and Im facing an error that I'm not able to solve.

I'm trying map a csv file into DF, but is returning an error.

```
// Adding schema to RDDs - Initialization
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import spark.implicits._

case class Employee(name: String, age: Long)
val employeeDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile.("./employee.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => Employee(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
employeeDF.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

var youngstersDF = spark.sql("SELECT name,age FROM employee WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 30")
youngstersDF.map(youngster => "Name: " + youngster(0)).show()
```

When I try map the name returns an error as described below:

The error returned is:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 21, 192.168.0.122, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "age"
```

The file content is:
name,age
John,28
Andrew,36
Clarke,22
Kevin,42

I googled it but no lucky in terms of solutions/answers.

Can someone please help?

With Many Thanks
Xavy

Answer (score 0):

You need to **`filter out the header`** from your data while converting to dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import spark.implicits._

case class Employee(name: String, age: Long)
val employeeRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("./employee.txt")

//storing header string
val header=employeeRDD.first()

//filter out the header from the data
val employeeDF = employeeRDD.filter(r => r!=header).map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => Employee(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()

employeeDF.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

sql("select * from employee").show()
//+------+---+
//|  name|age|
//+------+---+
//|  John| 28|
//|Andrew| 36|
//|Clarke| 22|
//| Kevin| 42|
//+------+---+
```

Just FYI you can use **`spark.read.csv`** with option header and pass the **schema** while reading.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val sch=new StructType().add("name",StringType).add("age",LongType)
val df=spark.read.option("header",true).option("delimiter",",").schema(sch).csv("./employee.txt")

df.show()
//+------+---+
//|  name|age|
//+------+---+
//|  John| 28|
//|Andrew| 36|
//|Clarke| 22|
//| Kevin| 42|
//+------+---+
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer.
I tested your suggestion on Zeppelin and Im using Spark 3. The error returned is:

'''
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 12, 192.168.0.122, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: Employee cannot be cast to Employee
'''
The second suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: @xavy, I tried same code in `spark-3` works as expected, Could you add steps that being executed in zeppelin notebook? and make sure your case class is not over ridden by some other process in zeppelin.

Comment: @xavy, If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I would try this-

```scala
 def getType[T: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag](obj: T) = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[T]
    val path = getClass.getResource("/csv/employee.txt").getPath
    val ds = spark.read
      .schema(ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Employee].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
      .option("header", true)
      .option("sep", ",")
      .csv(path)
      .as[Employee]
    println(getType(ds))
    /**
      * org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.som.spark.learning.Employee]
      */
    ds.show(false)
    ds.printSchema()
    /**
      * +------+---+
      * |name  |age|
      * +------+---+
      * |John  |28 |
      * |Andrew|36 |
      * |Clarke|22 |
      * |Kevin |42 |
      * +------+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- age: long (nullable = true)
      */
```

```
case class Employee(name: String, age: Long)
```

Comment: Please feel free to upvote+accept if it helps -https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/767994

Comment: sorry the previous comment. Many Thanks for you reply.
Is returning an error:

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: full stacktrace?